# List of Movies Question , Can we allow it?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should Questions on List of Movies be allowed ?  Like for Example

- List of movies with star crossed lovers
- List of movies with Disease as the main theme.
- Movies That have only 2 characters
- List of indie movies on relationships

and so on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many list questions may solicit opinions, but that's not the reason list questions are bad.  List questions are bad because they don't fit a question/answer format well.  A list question is one that solicits multiple correct answers, rather than a single correct answer.  When there are multiple correct answers, it's impossible to select the correct answer; and SE is all about finding *good, correct answers* to *expert-level questions.*  If we allow questions that *cannot have correct answers*, it's not fulfilling the goal of the SE network.

List questions are considered off-topic on every other SE site (as far as I know), and should be off-topic here, as well.

Answer (score 9):

List questions almost always are soliciting opinions, or asking for shopping advice. They're off-topic for being not constructive.

However, questions asking for lists may be on-topic. These are questions where there is a single correct list that can be contained in a single answer. An example is, "List of scenes in this movie?" (assuming question isn't general reference)

Comment: If `List of scenes in this movie` can be allowed , Then as per your argument , There may be some list questions with a short number of items on the list , Then they may also be allowed also because they can be contained in a single answer.

Comment: @GautamK That would require dedicated moderation per question to make sure users are following the format.

Comment: So in general they are disallowed , But there may be exceptions

Comment: well according to your answer this should not be closed
http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27512/what-movies-tv-shows-music-videos-etc-originated-from-snl/27517#27517
as the list I was requiring is a fixed list of shows and movies that is not opinion based and with only possible answer

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: NO!

Long answer:
List questions generate very little meaningful content to the network, and are generally a pain to get much info out of.  It’s hard to get a good answer to a question if you have to read through 10+ answers.  Another inherent issue is time.  List questions are usually open to time, so people will fly by and add the new hotness, making it that much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No, they have no value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just have to have moderation to differentiate between

"List of directors who put numbers in their movies (http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/821/are-there-any-other-directors-other-than-george-lucas-that-have-a-specific-num/824#824)" (I realize this isn't a list of movies question, but it's in the same vein, I was trying to find a specific example)

and

"List your top three Sidney Lumet movies"

I think there are a lot of movie questions (see the link above) that implicity ask for lists without asking directly.  A lot of questions can be answered with lists.  Banning list questions altogether seems ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if anybody feels like getting a list based on a property or want to know "If there is a movie where **X** is shown", we might want to just ask him to join in a friendly [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) to discuss about this. I think chat can give the answer in the best possible way!