# Does this question about director easter-eggs qualify as a List Question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[**This**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/821/are-there-any-other-directors-other-than-george-lucas-that-have-a-specific-num) question, while interesting, I fear may be a list question but I cannot be sure what the official policy on it is as it does not have one specific answer and by [**this**](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/list-of-movies-question-can-we-allow-it) meta question, list questions are explicitly off-topic.

Some feedback please, I have already thrown a close vote to get some attention from higher rep users as well.

Comment: It is clearly a list question, but also interesting. +1 close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a list question and must be burned with fire!