# Why is this question considered "Chatty, open-ended" and closed?

Tags: discussion

**[This one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8088/is-there-a-younger-jim-carrey-like-actor-out-there)**

Today I sadly see how this question was closed meaning that I will  not find an answer to that simple pledge.

Reading the FAQs I simply don't see how that question is not in liine with what this site is about.  Could it be closed because a small part of the elite did not like it or because I read the words but don't understand? I tried to clarify via comments but those who replied only did say 'i don't like it'. This question was closed because of "dislikes" :)

In simple words the question is: **These are the main skills of this old actor, is there one younger that can do that?**

It is not a subjective question. There's nothing to discuss about that.

If it is an undesirable kind of question then I would propose to edit a bit the standards around here. If this site will keep growing there will be more questions of that kind. Imagine you watch pulp fiction for the first time today, you may want to ask:

**This old movie is great I want to watch similar ones! What newer movie features cool gangsters and non linear story?**

That thing happens. You want to get more of what you like.

Who can give me reasonable answer?

Comment: Your question a list kind of question. I mean there is no exact answer. Read the faq for details http://movies.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: What is a "list kind of question"? Multiple questions?

Comment: I mean open-ended chatty kind of question.

Comment: A list question is one that can generate a number of different and equally correct answers. Unfortunately this is not a forum, it is a Q&A site - intended to generate the most 'correct' answers. Now M&TV is a softer subject than software development, but there is a limit to how open ended the questions can be. You can ask this on chat, but it both questions are clearly not in the spirit of stackexchange.

Comment: upvote for wanting clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Might I start out that I am also a huge Jim Carrey fan, so that I absolve all bias against the actor himself :)]

Stating my dislike of this question in the comment section is my way of saying "I won't close this, but the community probably will".  This is exactly what happened.

As @iandotkelly said, this question is **too** open-ended and opinion-driven to be a good fit for this site.  As a general rule across a majority of Stack Exchange sites, the question must **not be subjective**.  We do have relaxed rules because a lot of movies can be taken multiple ways and are left open to interpretation and therefore allow some subjectivity to questions.

However, the way this question is worded opens up a door we do not want to go on and likens itself to a *recommendation* question.

Just like asking:

> I like **The Matrix**, but no other **movie** seems to capture **camera work and computer culture**, are there any **movies** now that do this?

This question would be closed *immediately* as a recommendation, which are not allowed on this site.  [from memory, I think only the now-defunct Literature.SE allowed recommendations].]

Apply the same question but replace the bolded parts with an actor:

> I like **Tom Cruise** but no other **actor** seems to capture **insanity and grace**, are there any **actors** now that do this?

Do you see my point?

---

TLDR: It's a recommendation based on an actor instead of a genre.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I believe I see it. If your example question was: "I like The Matrix, what other movies offer a plot with machine domination over human and shooting scenes with sunglasses?" you think it would be positive?

See my interest here is not cry for a closed question but about how to properly ask about related material, which I think would be very useful

Comment: The typical rule for related material that we have found to work is just like in the example you used in the comments in @Mistu4u's answer.  Directly comparing one work to another in some manner, whether it be asking if one work is an inspiration to another, whether a plot element or object in one work is a nod to another.  Even using a [BlogOverflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to present your own objective evidence why (for example) Adventure Time has more adult themes than Archer.

Comment: Very good examples!

Comment: ok thank you Tyler

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for your question being closed. But observing the question I understand now, why it is closed. I voted to close it myself. I think you can get the reasons of any question being closed beneath the comments of the questions. The problems which I can see in your questions are:

**1) Primary reason (for what I voted to close):**- Your question, like @Tylershads pointed out, *can be subjective and opinionated as a question*. You see you may think a particular junior actor to be compared to Jim Carrey, whereas other may find different persons in their mind and there would be different reasons for everyone for them to compare with Jim. So it cannot meet a perfect answer, which is a necessary criteria for SE sites. Also, the answers would be *subjunctive* and too broad, not helping much viewers. Movies.SE does not welcome these sort of questions. A similar question asked by me *Why is joker so popular* (deleted it a while back) was closed for the same reason. Different persons can have different reasons for liking joker. Answer to your question should sound the same. Answerer 1 can say: **I think X is like Jim** again Answerer 2 can say: **I think Y is like Jim**, which would be non-deterministic by nature.

**2) Secondary reason:**- Like @ankit said, your question seemed to be "List Question" which is off-topic in every SE site including [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/list-of-movies-question-can-we-allow-it). Readers might have got an indication that you are wanting a "list" of "Jim like actors" or "a list of movies done by any Jim like actor", which is not allowed here.

Comment: Thanks for the first explanation.  But still I don't see it. I picked a random question, this http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18/did-existenz-influence-inception.

That generated "a list of answers" because this is not a "hard" subject, like say, stack overflow. The question is not closed and answered nicely. I think in my kind of question people would answer who is a similar actor and the most reckoned will get the upvotes

The deal here is, will m&tv exclude this kind of question? I am sure they are useful, the matter is : will older members accept them?

Comment: btw note that there are bulletpoints to define what is a similar actor. Objective.  Someone who answers for instance, Pamela anderson would get a downvoted question.

Comment: @quinestor See my answer, while that question may have multiple answers, but this is because the argument has been made by both sides and it can be summed down to a "Yes it did" or a "No it didn't" And both answers offer a detailed comparison and analysis of both movies.

Comment: I had not joined here when the question was asked.:P But jokes apart, I think whether acting quality of X is same as Y or not is far more abstract to answer than answering if movie X has influenced Y or not.there are answers with references in the question where Nolan has made some definite comments. But imagine answers to your question consists of only vague guesses and no definite references!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Faq](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

And your question fall under the hood of Chatty, open-ended questions. Which is not accepted here.

> **You can ask question about** -
>
> - Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Movies/TV Identifying a
> - Movie or TV series (see below for details) Questions about a Movie/TV
> - show's production. The works of a director / an actor / a writer
> - related to Movies/TV
>
> Movies also includes Made-For-TV movies, Direct-to-DVD, and
>   Mini-Series.